# Differentiation / Limit problem from intro real analysis textbook

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Assume that $f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(0)$ exists. If the sequences $\alpha_n, \beta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, define the difference quotient $$D_n = \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n}.$$

Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} D_n = f'(0)$ under each of the following conditions:

(i) $\alpha_n < 0< \beta_n$.

(ii) $0<\alpha_n < \beta_n$ and $ \frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} \leq M$.

(iii) $f'(x)$ exists and is continuous for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

I'm trying to teach myself real analysis. My proof-writing abilities so far are shaky. My attempt for (i): I tried to manipulate $\lim_{n\to\infty} D_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n}$ until it is equivalent to $f'(0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t) - f(0)}{t}$. I got $\lim_{n\to\infty} D_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(0)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\alpha_n) - f(0)}{\alpha_n - \beta_n}$, which isn't very far. I'm not sure how to involve condition (i) in the proof.

Comment: Hint for (i) and (ii): $f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n) = \bigl(f(\beta_n) - f(0)\bigr) - \bigl(f(\alpha_n) - f(0)\bigr)$. Hint for (iii): Mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

(i) It is sometimes fruitful to show that a certain difference converges to zero, rather than making a straight-forward calculation. Using this case as a sample (in the hope of it being useful, since you said to be self-teaching)
$$\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-f'(0)=\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)+f(0)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-f'(0)\frac{\beta_n-\alpha_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}=\\=\left(\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right)\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-\left(\frac{f(\alpha_n)-f(0)}{\alpha_n}-f'(0)\right)\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}$$

Now we observe that
$0\leq\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-f'(0)\right|=\left|\left(\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right)\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-\left(\frac{f(\alpha_n)-f(0)}{\alpha_n}-f'(0)\right)\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}\right|\leq$

$\leq\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right|\left|\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}\right|+\left|\frac{f(\alpha_n)-f(0)}{\alpha_n}-f'(0)\right|\left|\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}\right|\leq$

$\leq K\left(\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right|+\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right|\right)$

A constant $K$ such that the last inequality holds exists because, since $\beta_n>0>\alpha_n$, $\frac{|\beta_n|}{|\beta_n-\alpha_n|}=\frac{|\beta_n|}{|\beta_n|+|\alpha_n|}\leq1$ and the same goes for the other one.

But since $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}K\left(\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right|+\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(0)}{\beta_n}-f'(0)\right|\right)=0$, we just proved that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left|\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}-f'(0)\right|=0$, as we wanted.

You may also note that the same proof can be used for point (ii).

(iii) You can indeed use Lagrange's theorem (a.k.a. "mean value theorem"), which can be found in any handbook of elementary Analysis.